# How can I use Filepond to generate multiple image sizes for responsive designs?

Tags: javascript, filepond

I'm trying to use the Filepond JavaScript plugin to automatically generate transforms of images for  Bootstrap breakpoints (768px, 576px, etc) during one image upload, but am running into issues.

1. It seems like the imageTransform plugin can't be used without the imageResize plugin, which is generating a resized and upscaled image I don't want - I think I should just be generating transforms instead of mixing sources.
2. I don't really want the images to upscale if they're smaller than the breakpoint, but "imageResizeUpscale: false" seems to be breaking the imageTransform plugin functionality.

Has anyone tackled this before or worked with Filepond? My code is something like this, modified from a CodePen demo (https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/ydYxOE):

```css
.filepond--root {
    max-width:20em;
}

body {
    padding: 2em;
}

img {
    margin: 1em 2em 0 0;
    border-radius: .25em;
    box-shadow: 0 .125em .5em rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="file" multiple>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-resize/dist/filepond-plugin-image-resize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-transform/dist/filepond-plugin-image-transform.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-crop/dist/filepond-plugin-image-crop.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
<script>
    
    FilePond.registerPlugin(
        FilePondPluginImageCrop,
        FilePondPluginImagePreview,
        FilePondPluginImageResize,
        FilePondPluginImageTransform
    );

    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    allowImageTransform: true,
        imageCropAspectRatio: 1,
        imageResizeTargetWidth: 2000,
        imageResizeMode: 'contain',
    //imageResizeUpscale: false,
      imageTransformVariants: {
        thumb_medium_: transforms => {
            transforms.resize.size.width = 768;
            return transforms;
        },
        thumb_small_: transforms => {
            transforms.resize.size.width = 576;
            return transforms;
        }
      },
        onaddfile: (err, fileItem) => {
            console.log(err, fileItem.getMetadata('resize'));
        },
        onpreparefile: (fileItem, outputFiles) => {
            outputFiles.forEach(output => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(output.file);
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of only setting `transforms.resize.size.width = 768;` also set the `height` property, that should solve the issue.